# Deterministic CTR_DRBG in OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, entropy

I'm using the OpenSSL EVP API in C to call the CTR_DRBG implementation and I'm having some trouble getting the output to be deterministic.

Configuration and all input arguments are fixed (entropy, nonce, personalization string, addtional inputs 1 and 2). I can’t seem to achieve passing all these parameters to OpenSSL.

First I use the EVP_RAND_fetch function with [`CTR-DRBG`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/EVP_RAND-CTR-DRBG.html). However, I think this enforces the use of an external source of entropy.

Setting the entropy is done through the `EVP_RAND_CTX_set_params` and `OSSL_RAND_PARAM_TEST_ENTROPY` parameter, but this one is only documented in the [`TEST-RAND`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/EVP_RAND-TEST-RAND.html) fetch string. And if I use `TEST-RAND`, I can’t find a way to tell OpenSSL to use CTR_DRBG.

Here’s one of the known-to-be-correct test vectors I’m trying to validate against:

```
Configuration: AES-128, no reseed, no prediction resistance, use derivation function
EntropyInput: 890eb067acf7382eff80b0c73bc872c6
Nonce: aad471ef3ef1d203
Personalization string, additionalInput_1, additionalInput_2: (empty)
Output size: 512 bits
Expected output: a5514ed7095f64f3d0d3a5760394ab42062f373a25072a6ea6bcfd8489e94af6cf18659fea22ed1ca0a9e33f718b115ee536b12809c31b72b08ddd8be1910fa3
```

Comment: I'm actually wondering if this is wise since the OpenSSL API seems to comply mostly with the NIST specifications for DRBG. It may be better to directly implement `EVP_RAND` to make sure it is free of side effects such as reseeding through the OS, assuming you require the `EVP_RAND` API of course.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/13751#issuecomment-752614911) is a link to the OpenSSL DRBG test source code that you could possibly use as a blueprint for your own implementation.